# Antiferromagnetic ordering

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output

[image: Antiferromagnetic ordering]

**Antiferromagnetism** is what IBM researchers used to jump from a *1 terabyte disk* to a *100 terabyte disk* in the same amount of atoms.

In materials that exhibit antiferromagnetism, the magnetic moments of atoms or molecules, usually related to the spins of electrons, align in a regular pattern with neighboring spins (on different sublattices) pointing in opposite directions.

Your job is to write a program that draws the ordering of antiferromagnetic atoms like the picture shown above. You must be able to have at least four sets of pairs, though you may have more.

Each pair must be shown as follows, though they must be **actual arrows**:

```
 up  down
down  up
 up  down
```

Your output can be in ascii art or graphical output.

You can make only a function or a whole program, but it must take an input and draw that many pairs. Examples with *only words*:

Input: 1

```
 up  down
down  up
 up  down
```

Input: 2

```
 up  down  up  down 
down  up  down  up  
 up  down  up  down
```

Acceptable arrows:

- `↑` and `↓`
- `⇅` and `⇵`
- `/|\` and `\|/`

Please put your answers in **Language, X bytes** format, as it's easy to read. The least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: You may want to give more constraints on the output, since most answers would then be low quality for the sake of golfing. Maybe take input of how many pairs to output and give example output that must be adhered to.

Comment: @Maltysen Any arrows are ok, but I'd like to see graphical ones. It also depends on what type of ascii-esc arrow it is, such as `/|\\` or a unicode one.

Comment: The output is always three rows right?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Correct

Comment: "Any arrows" sounds pretty ambiguous to me - what about `^v`?

Comment: @Sp3000 No, cause they don't have the little tails.

Comment: Are these arrows allowed: `⇅` and `⇵`? ([unicode code points U+21C5 and U+21F5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Arrows))

Comment: @DigitalTrauma They are perfect!

Comment: @Phase I rolled back your edit.  Changing the scoring from bytes to chars will significantly change scores for a lot of these answers.  Changing the rules after getting 15 answers is generally frowned upon.

Comment: would you accept /\ and \/ as arrows?

Comment: @BetaDecay As I said about `^v`, they've got to have tails.

Comment: @Phase Damn, that's a shame

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## APL, <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```
⍉(2×⎕)3⍴'↑↓'
```

This constructs a 2n x 3 matrix, where n is the input (`⎕`), filled with the characters `↑` and `↓`. The transpose (`⍉`) of this matrix is then printed.

You can [try it online](http://baruchel.hd.free.fr/apps/apl/#code=%E2%8D%89(2%C3%97%E2%8E%95)3%E2%8D%B4'%E2%86%91%E2%86%93').

Comment: Nice abuse of the APL character set. I guess other answers can also use this character set, though.

Comment: @jimmy23013: The APL code page is EBCDIC-based. Not sure how many languages can handle that.

Comment: @Dennis Can't the program itself be in ASCII (or some gibberish in EBCDIC) while it prints EBCDIC strings? The shortcut for newlines would be gone, though. Alternatively, the Windows console seemed to print `\x18\x19` as `↑↓`.

Comment: Or [these codepages](http://pastebin.com/NkwixNNd).

Comment: @jimmy23013: Yes, I just talked about old consoles [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22694285#22694285). The gibberish might work, but it's probably worth a meta discussion.

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, 15 bytes (11 chars)

```
V3.>*Q"↑↓"N
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V3.%3E*Q%22%E2%86%91%E2%86%93%22N&input=4&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
              implicit: Q = input number
V3            for N in [0, 1, 2]:
      "↑↓"       string "↑↓"
    *Q           repeat Q times
  .>      N      rotate the string by N
```

Answer (score 12):

## Java, <s>313</s> 296 bytes

Here's an example that displays arrows graphically:

```java
import java.awt.*;void f(int n){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int k=0,l,m,o;k<n*6;o=k%6,l=o/2*10+32,m=k/6*20+(k++%2==0?19:29),g.fillPolygon(new int[]{m+4,m,m+4,m+4,m+6,m+6,m+10},o==1|o==2|o==5?new int[]{l+9,l+5,l+5,l,l,l+5,l+5}:new int[]{l,l+5,l+5,l+9,l+9,l+5,l+5},7));}}.show();}
```

In a more readable format:

```java
import java.awt.*;
void f(int n) {
    new Frame() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for (int k = 0, l, m, o; k < n*6;){
                o = k % 6;
                l = o / 2 * 10 + 32;
                m = k / 6 * 20 + (k++ % 2 == 0 ? 19 : 29);
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] {m+4,m,m+4,m+4,m+6,m+6,m+10},
                              o == 1 || o == 2 || o == 5 ?
                                  new int[] {l+9,l+5,l+5,l,l,l+5,l+5} :
                                  new int[] {l,l+5,l+5,l+9,l+9,l+5,l+5},
                              7);
            }
        }
    }.show();
}
```

The display for 5 as input:

[image: Display for 5 as input]

You'll have to resize the window that appears to see the arrows. I tried to make it so that none of them would appear "chopped off" by the window's inside border, but it may appear that way on certain platforms.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, 18 bytes (14 chars)

```
ri3*"↑↓"*3/zN*
```

Generate the columns (which form a repeating pattern) then transpose.

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri3*%22%E2%86%91%E2%86%93%22*3%2FzN*&input=4).

---

**Alternative 18 bytes:**

```
3,ri"↑↓"*fm>N*
```

Rotate the string `"↑↓"*n` by 0, 1 or 2 times.

Answer (score 7):

### CJam (15 chars, 19 bytes)

```
ri"↑↓"*_(+1$]N*
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%22%E2%86%91%E2%86%93%22*_%28%2B1%24%5DN*&input=4)

Comment: Win condition is bytes, not chars.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: The challenge specified **Language, X bytes** format. You have it in char format, but unicode characters are worth 2 bytes so your actual score is 17 **bytes**

Comment: @Levi According to [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#↑↓) they're 3 bytes each.

Comment: @isaacg ah my bad

Answer (score 7):

### **Befunge, 71 bytes**

My first answer, so please be gentle with me :o)

Annoying alignment issues resulted in a few wasted bytes, if you have any improvements for me I'd love to hear them!

```
&::3>:2% #v_0#v" \|/ "<
  >\^,*52<> 0#v" /|\ "<
:#^_$1-:#^_@  >:#,_$\1-
```

Input: 4

```
 /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/ 
 \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\ 
 /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/  /|\  \|/
```

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 14 bytes

```
0000000: 332c 7269 2218 1922 2a66 6d3e 4e2a       3,ri".."*fm>N*
```

This requires a supporting terminal that renders [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) like this:

[image]

The non-pointy part of the code turned out to be identical to [@Sp3000's alternative version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52912).

---

## CJam, 17 bytes

```
ri"⇅⇵⇅"f*N*
```

Cheaty double arrow version, with credits to @DigitalTrauma.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%22%E2%87%85%E2%87%B5%E2%87%85%22f*N*&input=3)

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 16 bytes (12 chars)

```
J"↑↓"V3*~_JQ
```

Example:

```
Input: 4
Output:
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>131</s> 122 bytes

```py
from turtle import*
for k in range(input()*6):z=k/3+k%3&1;pu();goto(k/3*32,z*32^k%3*64);pd();seth(z*180+90);fd(32);stamp()
```

Well... I beat <s>C</s> Java I guess?

[image]

---

I've chosen height `32` for the arrows, which is pretty large, so after a while the turtle starts drawing offscreen. If you want everything to fit for large inputs, you can either make the arrows smaller by replacing the `32`s, or use `screensize()` (I'm not sure if there's a meta post on offscreen output...)

Comment: So... when are going to add turtle graphics to Pyth?

Comment: Surely for golfing purposes you should choose a single digit number for the sizing...

Comment: @BetaDecay For single digit sizing the tail is barely visible, since it's obscured by the turtle

Answer (score 4):

## GNU sed, 25 bytes

I found the `⇅` and `⇵` unicode arrow symbols, which allow more shortening and [they have been allowed by this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52903/antiferromagnetic-ordering?noredirect=1#comment126360_52903):

```
h
s/1/⇅/g
H
G
s/1/⇵/g
```

[Input is in unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5343/11259), so e.g. 4 is `1111`:

```
$ echo 1 | sed -f antiferro.sed
⇅
⇵
⇅
$ echo 1111 | sed -f antiferro.sed
⇅⇅⇅⇅
⇵⇵⇵⇵
⇅⇅⇅⇅
$
```

---

Previous answer in case `⇅` and `⇵` are disallowed:

## GNU sed, 39 bytes

```
s/1/↑↓/g
s/.*/&a&↑\n&/
s/a↑/\n/
```

Comment: Whenever I see "GNU sed" at the top of a post, I don't even need to scroll down to know who posted it.

Comment: @AlexA. [This guy?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39490/toby-speight) ;-)

Comment: Input is in unary?! Is that a general for the language or something you programmed in?

Comment: What a nefarious answer :-)

Comment: @BetaDecay Re unary input - please check out [the linked meta-question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary). Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @xebtl Thats a lot of the fun of it for me :) - trying to find answers that push the limits of the rules, but are still (hopefully) valid

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yeah I think it makes sense... So you're treating the unary number as string and finding its length?

Comment: @BetaDecay thats the unique property of unary strings - their numeric value is equal to their length.  The meta question/answer allows for this strictly for languages that don't have native arithmetic (e.g. `sed`).  This is particularly handy for this question, because the output of the required length can easily be generated from the unary input. Cheaty? perhaps - but the meta answer consensus seems to be OK with it.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby 39 (or 44) characters, 43 (or 48) bytes

According to https://mothereff.in/byte-counter the arrow characters are 3 bytes each!

```
->(n){a=['↑↓'*n]*3;a[1]=a[1].reverse;a}
```

An anonymous function which returns an array. If the function has to print the array, it should end with `puts a` for 5 more bytes.

Example use

```
f=->(n){a=['↑↓'*n]*3;a[1]=a[1].reverse;a}

puts f.call(6)
```

Gives

```
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, <s>41</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes (28 characters)

```
3$(,:|.)(2*".1!:1[1)$ucp'↑↓'
```

I have never programmed anything in J so this took me a while, and it's most definitely not the best way to do it.

This waits for you to input a number when run before outputing the arrows.

Comment: What do you mean you haven't programmed anything in J? I seem to recall a certain J answer which got you over 1k rep. ;)

Comment: @AlexA. Doing simple arithmetics is not really what I would call programming. When I posted that answer I really didn't know anything about J besides the right to left priority

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 2, 66 bytes

```
let f={n in(0..<n*3).map{print("↑↓",appendNewline:$0%n==n-1)}}
```

If Swift would be just a liiiitle bit less verbose, it wouldn't even be that bad for golfing (I'm looking at you, named parameter `appendNewline`)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>169</s> <s>170</s> <s>162</s> <s>125</s> <s>123</s> <s>105</s> <s>119</s> 107 bytes

So, I though I might as well give this a go, even though this is obviously not the winner :)

Golfed:

```
n,i,j;main(){n=getchar();n=atoi(&n);for(;j++<3;){for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("%.3s ","⇅⇵"+(j%2)*3);puts("");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* n -> Number of columns, i & j -> Loop counters */
n,i,j;

main()
{
    /* Get the number of iterations from stdin */
    n = getchar();
    n = atoi(&n); /* Thanks @AndreaBiondo */

    for (; j++ < 3;)
    {
        /* Print rows of arrows */
        for (i = 0; i++ < n;)
            printf("%.3s ","⇅⇵" + (j % 2) * 3);

        /* Print a newline */
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Input: 4
⇵ ⇵ ⇵ ⇵ 
⇅ ⇅ ⇅ ⇅ 
⇵ ⇵ ⇵ ⇵
```

#### Update:

See it run [here](http://ideone.com/zHfFEo)

Comment: You can do `for(j=0;j++<3;)` and the same with `i`

Comment: @ThomasKwa aha... well spotted. thanks

Comment: `i` and `j` are globals, so they're initialized to zero. You can drop `i=0` and `j=0`.

Comment: Also, you can exploit little-endianess and zero initialization to use `n` as a buffer: `n=getchar();n=atoi(&n);`

Comment: @AndreaBiondo when i remove i=0 and j=0, all the output is on one line. can you reproduce this? i'm using gcc 4.9.2

Comment: I just noticed, this does not provide the correct output. Apart from the uneven spacing (which is easy to fix), the second row is not in the opposite direction - is it just me?

Comment: oops... both of those are errors in my code... will fix

Comment: Sorry, `i=0` in the inner loop must stay there :) My bad. `j=0` can be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>66</strike> <strike>63</strike> <strike>53</strike> 47 bytes (<strike>62</strike> <strike>55</strike> <strike>49</strike> 41 characters)

```
f=n=>`⇅
⇵
⇅`.replace(/./g,'$&'.repeat(n))
```

Props to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52903/antiferromagnetic-ordering/52930) for finding the ⇅ and ⇵ characters and allowing me to shave off more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 30 bytes

```
|:((2*".1!:1<1),3)$ucp'↑↓'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 37 bytes

***EDIT:*** corrected from the earlier stripe-antiferromagnetic version.  Thanks @beta-decay for catching my mistake.

```
f=@(n)repmat(["⇅";"⇵";"⇅"],1,n)
```

Defines a function `f(n)`.  Sample output:

```
octave:4> f(1)
ans =

⇅
⇵
⇅

octave:5> f(5)
ans =

⇅⇅⇅⇅⇅
⇵⇵⇵⇵⇵
⇅⇅⇅⇅⇅
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ƵηSnŽXæ+ç×»
```

Bug-fixed and -6 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

Uses `⇅` and `⇵`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//8a1zrdTbsW9WMOmK8Onw5fCu///Mw) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4/T@29dz24LyjeyMOL9M@vPzw9EO7/@sc2mb/HwA).

**Slightly larger simplified approach - 15 bytes in UTF-8 (8 characters):**

```
"⇅⇵"ĆS×»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6VF766P2rUpH2oIPTz@0@/9/YwA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4/Vd61N76qH2r0pG24MPTD@3@r3Nom/1/AA).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately the 05AB1E codepage doesn't contain the arrow characters, so we have to create them ourselves or use UTF-8 encoding for the entire program.

```python
Ƶη           # Push compressed integer 171
  S          # Convert it to a list of digits: [1,7,1]
   n         # Square each: [1,49,1]
    ŽXæ+     # Add compressed integer 8644 to each: [8645,8693,8645]
        ç    # Convert them to characters with these codepoints: ["⇅","⇵","⇅"]
         ×   # Repeat each character the (implicit) input amount of times as strings
          »  # And join this list of strings by newlines
             # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

"⇅⇵"        # Push string "⇅⇵"
     Ć       # Enclose, appending it's own head: "⇅⇵⇅"
      S      # Convert it to a list of characters: ["⇅","⇵","⇅"]
       ×»    # Same as above
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶη` is `171` and `ŽXæ` is `8644`.

Comment: I think `⇅` is meant as two arrows, one up and one down. This allows for a shorter solution: https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//8a1zrdTbsW9WMOmK8Onw5fCu///Mw

Comment: @ovs Oops.. I read it correctly, but implement it incorrectly. Not sure how I didn't notice that.. And thanks. I especially like that `ƵηSn`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes (62 chars)

That includes the Unicode character counted as three bytes each as well as the mandatory newline counted as one byte.

Uses recursion as inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52876/22867). I tried it non-recursively but generating a defined array took too many characters, although someone else might know how to do it better than me.

```js
f=n=>(g=(a,i)=>i?g(`
↓↑`[i%(n*2+1)&&1+i%2]+a,i-1):a)('',n*6+2)
```

#### Demo

As with all ES6 answers, they are demonstrable in Firefox, Edge, and Safari 9 only at time of writing:

```js
f = n => (g = (a, i) => i ? g(`
↓↑` [i % (n * 2 + 1) && 1 + i % 2] + a, i - 1) : a)('', n * 6 + 2)

console.log = x => document.getElementById('O').innerHTML += x + '\n';

console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(2));
console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(32));
```

```html
<pre><output id=O></output></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript, 60 bytes (58 chars)

Comprehensions make it easy without recursion:

```coffee
f=(n,x='')->x+='\n⇵⇅'[i%(n+1)&&1+i%2]for i in[1..n*3+2];x
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 33 bytes

As a function:

```
f=->n{[s="↑↓"*n,s.reverse,s]}
```

Example:

```
> puts f[3]
↑↓↑↓↑↓
↓↑↓↑↓↑
↑↓↑↓↑↓
```

## Ruby, 37 bytes

Full program which takes input from stdin:

```
puts s="↑↓"*gets.to_i,s.reverse,s
```

Comment: *You can make only a function or a whole program, but it must take an input and draw that many pairs.*

Comment: @Dennis ok, I'm on it

Comment: We seem to have a misunderstanding. I posted the quote to show that a function is in fact valid, since you implied in your original revision that a full program was required by the question.

Comment: @Dennis No problem. I was just thinking that returning 3 strings wasn't really "drawing", but I guess it doesn't matter. Anyways, got both versions golfed down a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, 55 Bytes

```
"⇅⇵⇅"{:&3*1-:0(?;\
|.!09v!?%&:&:{o:}/
oa{~}/|.!09
```

Try it online [here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground), inputting the desired length as initial stack value.

Non ⇅⇵ solution, 59 Bytes:

```
"↓↑"{:&3*>1-:0(?;{:{\
 |.!09v!?%&:&:oo}}@:/
9oa{$}/|.!0
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>117</strike> <strike>89</strike> 85 bytes

```
i;main(j,v)char**v;{j=2*atol(v[1])+1;for(;i++<3*j;)printf(i%j?i%2?"↑":"↓":"\n");}
```

Ungolfed:

```
i;
main(j,v)
char**v; // Credit to @AndreaBiondo for brilliant idea that I will use a lot in future golfed programs :)
{
    j = 2*atol(v[1])+1;
    for(;i++<3*j;)
        printf(i%j?i%2?"↑":"↓":"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 150 bytes

```java
static void g(int n){n*=2;f(n,0);f(n,1);f(n,0);}static void f(int n,int d){String l="";for(n+=d;n-->d;)l+=(n%2==0)?"↓":"↑";System.out.println(l);}
```

Output of `g(2)`:

```
↑↓↑↓
↓↑↓↑
↑↓↑↓
```

Comment: I think that you're required to output arrows, so I'd suggest that you change your example output and code to make it *absolutely clear* that you aren't breaking the rules :)

Comment: @BetaDecay I see some approved arrows have been listed and I haven't made the cut! So following your advice I've changed it

Answer (score 1):

## BBC BASIC, 70 bytes

```
INPUTx:n$=STRING$(x,"/|\\|/"):PRINTn$:PRINTSTRING$(x,"\|//|\"):PRINTn$
```

This can probably be golfed more

Answer (score 1):

## C, 97 bytes

Takes the input from the first command-line parameter, e.g. `main 4`. Supports up to `357913940` pairs. In C you can't use multibyte characters as `char`s but they work fine as strings.

```c
i,n;main(c,v)char**v;{n=atoi(v[1]);for(i=6*n+3;i--;)printf("%s",i%(2*n+1)?i%2?"↓":"↑":"\n");}
```

It is smaller as a function, but the other C answers were complete programs so I did that too. It would be 69 bytes:

```c
i;f(n){for(i=6*n+3;i--;)printf("%s",i%(2*n+1)?i%2?"↓":"↑":"\n");}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 47 bytes

Port of [my BBC BASIC answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52997/30525), taking advantage of how Python can easily reverse strings.

```
n=r"/|\\|/"*input();print n+"\n"+n[::-1]+"\n"+n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Went through a good few different methods but couldn't do better than 16 then I realised a port of [Kevin's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212215/58974) would come in a bit shorter.

```
#«ì £çX²d8644
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=I6vsIKPnWLJkODY0NA&input=Mw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Dj`, 11 bytes

```
‛↑↓3*½ÞTvṅ*
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Dj&code=%E2%80%9B%E2%86%91%E2%86%933*%C2%BD%C3%9ETv%E1%B9%85*&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to Aaron Miller

Comment: [11 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Dj&code=%E2%80%9B%E2%86%91%E2%86%933*%C2%BD%C3%9ETv%E1%B9%85*&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>45</s> 55 bytes

edit: modified arrows

Pretty straightforward approach. Doesn't work with unicode arrows, though.

```
def f(n):x=" /|\\ \\|/"*n;print x+"\n "+x[::-1]+"\n"+x
```

Comment: if you look at the comments in the original post, you will see that you are _specifically_ not allowed to use `^v` arrows as they do not have a tail

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that. Changed it into "/|\", hope it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

## R, <s>60</s> 62 bytes

Takes input from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT.  Creates a 3 x *(2 * input)* array, adds a column of carriage returns and then outputs the transposed array.

```
cat(t(cbind(array(c('↑','↓'),c(3,2*scan())),'\n')),sep='')
```

Test run

```
cat(t(cbind(array(c('↑','↓'),c(3,2*scan())),'\n')),sep='')
1: 25
2: 
Read 1 item
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑
↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓
```

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl 49 bytes

No winner but at least it's competitive:

```
foreach x {⇅ ⇵ ⇅} {puts [string repeat $x $argv]}
```

Comment: You can save bytes using `lmap` instead of `foreach`

Comment: And `string repeat`can be abbreviated to `string re`

Comment: And I am not sure, but implementing it as a `proc` retrieving a side effect of `lmap` returning values and replacing `$argv` by someone one-letter variable may save bytes.

Answer (score -1):

### Swift 2.0, 79 bytes

Nothing clever...

```
let p=3;for x in 0...2{print((0..<p*2).reduce(""){$0+["↑","↓"][($1+x)%2]})}
```

Comment: This would need to be put in a function, having to change the code for input isn't allowed